# Criterion for being a simple group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

In [this work](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.11.9657&rep=rep1&type=pdf) it's written that

> A group $G$ is simple if and only if the diagonal subgroup of $G \times G$ is a
>   maximal subgroup.

How can I prove it?

Comment: I am surprised I have not heard of this criterion before.

Comment: Indeed. It reminds me of a characterization of a Hausdorff space $X$ as one such that $\Delta \subset X \times X$ is closed.

Comment: There is also a similar result for rings. A commutative ring $R$ with $1$ is a field (ie. has no nontrivial proper ideals) if and only if the diagonal subring is a maximal subring of $R \times R$.

Comment: Is there a category-theoretic generalization? This feels like some sort of rigidity criterion.

Answer (score 3):

($\Rightarrow$): Suppose $G$ is simple, and $H\le G\times G$ is a subgroup containing the diagonal subgroup and some $(g,h)$ with $g\ne h$. Let $N\le G$ be the subgroup of elements $n$ such that $(e,n)\in H$, which is nontrivial since $(e,g^{-1}h)\in H$. Furthermore $N$ is normal, since if $(e,n)\in H$ then $(g,g)(e,n)(g^{-1},g^{-1})=(e,gng^{-1})\in H$. Thus by simplicity $N=G$, so $(e,g)\in H$ for all $g\in G$. By an identical argument, $(g,e)\in h$ for all $g\in G$, so clearly $H=G\times G$. Thus the diagonal subgroup is maximal.

($\Leftarrow$): Suppose $G$ is not simple, so we have some nontrivial proper normal subgroup $N$. Let $H=\{(g,ng):g\in G, n\in N\}$, which is a subgroup since if $g,g'\in G$ and $n,n'\in N$ we have
$$(g,ng)(g',n'g')=(gg',ngn'g')=(gg',ngn'g^{-1}gg')\in H$$
since $gg'\in G$ and $ngn'g^{-1}\in N$. This contains the diagonal subgroup but is still proper, so the diagonal subgroup is not maximal.