# Property of isomorphic subgroups in finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have the following question:

Does there exist a finite group $G$ and two subgroups $U,H\leq G$, s.t. the following properties are satisfied:

a) $H\cong U$.

b) There is **no** subgroup $L$, s.t. $U\lneq L \lneq G$

c) There exists a subgroup $K$, s.t. $H\lneq K \lneq G$.

I already know, that this implies that $H$ is not conjugated to $U$.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian simple group. Then in $G \times G$, the diagonal subgroup

$$D = \{(g,g): g \in G\}$$

is maximal (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731712/criterion-for-being-a-simple-group)) and $D \cong G$, but $G \times 1$ is not maximal.

Comment: And what is supergroup of $G\times 1$?

Comment: @Student: Try $G \times H$, for any $1 < H < G$.